# Data get messed up with simple query

Tags: google-sheets

please help me as I'm going crazy.
I can't figure out why this simple query suddenly doesn't work anymore.
Data get totally messed up. No clue why it suddenly changed. I had my dev worksheet working correctly for months, before.

This is a simplified copy of the problem I encountered :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1znRvjXjVMemNqIAgtBupe8s0Jjs36wFXzuyDHu1qgJ0/edit?usp=sharing
The problematic query : =query(Data!A2:V,"SELECT *"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't omit the header parameter. Try

```
=query(Data!A2:V,"SELECT *",0)
```

But if you want to return `Data!A2:V` you don't need query, you can simply do:

```
={Data!A2:V}
```

Comment: Ty, both formulas work with no problem; my bad forgetting the correct syntax.

I'm still puzzled why it worked for months and now returns this weird result.